# Как изменить свойство content у MainWindow по нажатию кнопки на странице?

Tags: c#, wpf

Т.е. изначально перед пользователем появляется MainWindow, которое отображает страницу с главным меню. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на соответствующую кнопку на этой странице, осуществлялся переход на другую. Т.е. нужно изменить свойство content у MainWindow, но я не понимаю как обратиться к этому свойству при описании эвента на странице.

Как итог должно получится что-то вроде:
Главное меню(несколько кнопок: новая игра, настройки, выход) -> нажатие кнопки -> переход на соответствующую страницу.

Comment: `Content = ...`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Но ведь я не могу обратиться к этому свойству, когда описываю действия при ивенте страницы. Приложение сразу падает и отображается "Приложение находится в режиме приостановки выполнения".

Comment: У вас страничная навигация? Или что?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы в приложении я мог переключаться между различными страницами, в зависимости от какого-то события. Т.е. мне нужно чередовать эти самые страницы. Я не понимаю как это сделать. Я могу задать Content для начальной страницы. Но я не могу изменить это свойство при описании эвента клика по кнопке, например, т.к. не понимаю как к нему обратиться описывая ивенты страницы, а не формы.

Comment: Расскажите подробнее о разметке своей, вы используете `Page` или что?

Comment: Да, создаю несколько страниц. Есть page с главным меню и page, которое должно отображаться после выбора пользователя. Изначально в MainWindow(в MainWindow.xaml.cs главной формы) прописываю следующее: Page1 page = new Page1(); Content = page;. Т.е. контенту формы присваиваю страницу, тем самым отображаю ее. На отображаемой page есть кнопка. И по ее нажатию, должна отобразиться Page2. Т.е. насколько я понимаю мне нужно изменить Context у формы с page1 на page2, но нужно как-то проверять событие нажатия на кнопу. Прошу прощения за замудренность)

Comment: Написал ответ, проверяйте, я не проверял.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Большое спасибо, все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз уж вы используете страницы (`Page`), то почему бы не воспользоваться встроенной навигацией WPF. Разместите в вашем окне любой навигационный контейнер (`Frame`) и отображайте свои страницы в нем.

Тогда, изначальный код будет такой:

```
var startPage = new Page1();
myFrame.Navigate(startPage);
```

Затем, из любой страницы (`Page`) можно перейти на любую другую с помощью сервиса навигации:

```
var nextPage = new Page2();
NavigationService.Navigate(nextPage);
```

Прямой доступ к родительскому окну при этом не потребуется.